# Returing Id from Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, site-design, site-script

I am attempting to grab the Id from a site script generated from Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb but am somehow unable to (?)  I want to use it in Add-PnPSiteDesign on the following line.

```
$SPTemplateSite = "https://TEST.sharepoint.com/teams/TeamTemplate"
$SiteScript = Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb -Url $SPTemplateSite -IncludeAll | Select Id
$SiteScript.Id
$SiteDesign = Add-PnPSiteDesign -Title "NH Project Site" -SiteScriptIds $SiteScript.Id -WebTemplate TeamSite
```

Getting an error "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'SiteScriptIds' because it is null."

Comment: If ID is null you might wanna make sure that you are connection to your admin site. From the docs:

"This command allows a Site Script to be generated off of an existing site on your tenant. Connect to your SharePoint Online Admin site before executing this command."

Answer (score 0):

The error shows the ID value is null, please check whether the ID value is obtained:

```
$SiteScript = Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb -Url $SPTemplateSite -IncludeAll | Select Id
$SiteScript
```